# Check if an element(text) has been deleted in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using jQuery to detect if an @ symbol has been inserted into a contenteditable div. When this is detected an ajax request is fired to the server to retrieve a list of users. A user would then click on the username (the function adduser will fire) and it will create a disabled textarea in the div.
Then I create an input dynamically with the id of the user selected as value (to notify them)

The problem I have is that if I delete a textarea (a username) from the contenteditable div, How do I know which textarea it is and so remove too the input which has the user id as value?

My script:

```js
function adduser(fname, lname, id, q)
    {
        var fname = fname;
        var lname = lname;
        var id = id;
        var word = '@' + q;
        var iid = 'id' + id;
    
      var old=$("#contentbox").html();
        var content=old.replace(word,""); 
        
    $("#contentbox").html(content);
        
    var E="<textarea class='textareamention' name="+id+" id="+iid+"  disabled >"+fname+"</textarea>";
                
    $("#contentbox").append(E);
                
      $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name: 'mention[]', id: id, value: id}).appendTo('#post');
    }
```

My contenteditable div id is contentbox.

Answer (score 0):

To remove element you can use [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method or just [`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) the element.

For Example:

```
$("#input_id").remove();
```

Or

```
$("#input_id").hide();
```

As I can see from your code, you are dynamically generating the TextArea. So at the same time, you can create an event as shown below.

If you want to detect if a particular element is removed, you'll have to set the event first.

```
$("#myTextArea").on("remove", function () {
    console.log("Element was removed");
})
```

Update:

Here is a working **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hrky1z24/)**.

Note: You'll have to also include [Jquery UI](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js) along with Jquery in your code, in order to use `remove()` event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But how can i know wich textarea has been deleted?

Comment: You can add events on multiple textarea, and the event will be fired up when an element is removed. See my answer.

Comment: The problem here is that my textareas have the same class/id. Please show me how to use your script in this specific case

Comment: When I try with $(".textareamention").on("remove", function () {} nothing happens

Comment: Check my updated answer. Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: @Dilak, please accept it as an answer if it works for you.

Comment: Your soluution is a good one but it is not exactly what i want to do. Indeed the textarea is removed when the user delete it by pressing the backstep key of the keyboard and not by clicking on a button. Can you help me with this?

Comment: So what i want is to know when the user delete what he has entered using the keyboard or even the mouse

Comment: To capture keyboard backspace press event you can do something like this  `$('#myTextArea').keyup(function(e) { if (e.keyCode == 8) alert('backspace trapped'); });`. And the write the logic of removing textarea or input inside the `if` statement.